How to reuse the backend of a MVC web application using session storage for a mobile app
I am converting my web application Ubiqer.com to a mobile app. I am currently using CodeIgniter 4 with jQuery and sessions to maintain state. I understand that my controllers need to return JSON responses to support the mobile app, but I have a few concerns:

CSRF Protection: My web application uses CSRF protection, where CodeIgniter sets a token in an input field and also in a cookie each time a form is submitted. How can I handle CSRF protection when my frontend and backend are on different domains?

Session Management: Is it possible to use server-side sessions for a mobile app? If so, what major challenges might I face in implementing this?


My solution was to use JWT token for authentication and using rest apis for the backend. But this will increase the development cost & time. For now we just want to have a mobile app.


You need to re-think the architecture, along the lines of your last comment. There isn't really a quick-fix. If you have a monolithic web app then switching to an API-based model is probably a big upheaval. Realistically you'd want all your frontends to use the same backend so you'd have to re-architect the web pages too, to use your new API.

A more realistic short-term solution might be to ensure that all your existing web pages are responsive and mobile-friendly, so they run well in a mobile browser. Unless you have a clear use case for the cost/benefit of making an actuall native mobile app, then that might actually be all you need. Obviously we don't know the specifics of what you're hoping to gain by having a native app. Bear in mind of course that you likely need at least two mobile apps (android and iOS), so that's an additional overhead too (even if you can use a unified app dev framework)

Hi @ADyson, thx for your reply.  What do you think about  this, if we create the restAPIs in same project and use the already created models and use JWT authentication only for those APIs. For frontend my client bought a react template from envato. We've planned to have only few modules in mobile not whole web app.

Well yes that might save you some time and obviously allow you to re-use some components, so you could have a hybrid system. Of course if the mobile app only needs a subset of functionality then you might not have to write a full set of API endpoints yet. And then CSRF and sessions are not things to worry about because you're implementing a different design pattern, with stateless REST APIs in the backend, and a fully client-side frontend framework handling current state of the UI.

@ADyson, my all controllers returns the json_encoded response especially for a CRUD operation and we call them through ajax.  I think they can be used for another frontend. But point where i'm getting confused most , how i'll handle the csrf . Currently codeigniter automatically injects token in cookies.  I'm using server side sessions. Is it possible to used for the mobile app aswell.

Not easily I would think, although I'm not a mobile app expert so it might be possible somehow, but the main problem is the server isn't generating the HTML of each view or form, and isn't maintaining session state. I would think you could replicate the CRUD controller actions relatively easily in an API, especially if a lot of the logic is (or can be) behind them in classes which are re-usable.
